# Hyperlinks don't copy from Excel to Excel when using Data Connection

Tags: excel, hyperlink, connection

I'm an end user who hosts a public Excel 2010 Workbook (without macros, so other users can feel safe) which contains all of the individual player stats for the Madden NFL Mobile game by EA Sports.

I've also created a non-public Macro-Enabled 2010 Workbook which I use to automate the extraction all of the relevant data from a 3rd party website and reparse all of that data into a spreadsheet layout I desire.

My first column of the Macro-Enabled Workbook contains the player's name with a hyperlink to that player's webpage on that 3rd party website, and the macro creates that hyperlink for me just fine.

When I use a Data Connection to automate the syncing of the data from the Macro Book to the Non-Macro Book, everything copies fine, except for the player's name which is only in plain text (no hyperlink).

I also tried to make that first column an excel hyperlink formula (instead of VBA's hyperlink function), but the formula won't transfer via the data connection either.

Is there something I can edit maybe inside of the Data Connection file (.odc) to accomplish my goal?

My only other workaround so far is to add 2 extra hidden columns containing the text link and player name, and then mucking around with the destination Table to make the first column a pre-defined excel HYPERLINK formula to convert the two columns back into a hyperlink.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I decided to just use a powershell script and batch file to do all of my copy/pasting, and skipping the whole Data Connection thing all together.

My "TransferMaddenData.ps1" PowerShell Code:

```
    $path = "C:\Users\Grego\Desktop\MaddenData.xlsm" 
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
    $Excel.visible = $false 
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.open($path) 
    $Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item("DataOutput") 
    $Rows = $Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    $Rows += 1
    $Cells = "A3:BD" + $Rows
    $Worksheet.activate()  
    $range = $WorkSheet.Range($Cells) 
    $range.Copy() | out-null 

    $path = "C:\Users\Grego\Desktop\Madden1.xlsm" 
    $Workbook2 = $Excel.Workbooks.open($path) 
    $Worksheet = $Workbook2.Worksheets.item("Raw Data") 
    $range = $Worksheet.Range("A3") 
    $Worksheet.Paste($range)  

    $Workbook2.Save()  
    $Workbook.Close()  
    $Excel.Quit() 
    Remove-Variable -Name excel 
    [gc]::collect() 
    [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

This is my "FixMadden.bat" batch file:

```
    @echo off
    color 1F
    echo.

    C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Users\Grego\Desktop\TransferMaddenData.ps1"

    :EOF
    echo Waiting seconds
    timeout /t 10 /nobreak > NUL
```

Hope this maybe helps someone else someday!